# SQL Server: SELECT value with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for a SQL solution to the following problem

> Return `USER` and `NUMBER` combination `WHERE PRIORITY = MIN(PRIORITY)` [`NULL` is equivalent to `MAX(PRIORITY + 1)`] ... in the case of ties in `PRIORITY`, break using lowest `LINEITEM`

FIELDS:

```
USER,
LINEITEM,
NUMBER,
PRIORITY
```

VALUES: ('X' signifies desired combination)

```
USER    LINEITEM    NUMBER  PRIORITY    
-------------------------------------
1       1           12345   NULL    
1       2           23456   2   
1       3           34567   1           X
2       1           9876    3   
2       2           98765   1           X
2       3           12345   2   
2       4           23456   1   
3       1           23456   NULL        X
3       2           12345   NULL    
4       1           34567   NULL    
4       2           45678   NULL    
4       3           12345   1           X
4       4           12345   2   
4       5           23456   1
```

Thanks in advance.

In response to PM 77-1,

My current method:

```
SELECT table1.user,table1.number
FROM table1
JOIN (
  SELECT user,
  CAST(MIN((COALESCE(priority,999) * 
  (10 ^ (5 - LEN(COALESCE(CAST(priority AS VARCHAR),'999'))))) + 
  lineitem) AS VARCHAR) AS selector 
  FROM table1 GROUP BY user 
  ) AS table2 
  ON table1.user = table2.user 
  AND table1.lineitem = CAST(RIGHT(table2.selector, 1) AS int)
  ORDER BY table1.user;
```

Comment: OK. What stops you from creating such query? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was attempting to perform the task using SELF-JOIN and NOT EXISTS, but kept getting inaccurate results.

My current solution is very inelegant, and I would like to understand how to accomplish it using set operations.

Comment: Please add your code to your question by using [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d57bc/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY [User]
            ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN Priority IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                Priority,
                LineItem
        ) AS rn
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT 
    [User], LineItem, Number, Priority
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Can probably simplify to `ISNULL(Priority, 99)` or similar if the priority is a predictably low number.